# How to set gradient in Circliful semicircle

Tags: jquery

This is my code i'm trying to make semicircle with percentage using Circliful, Im not getting gradient in this semicircle
I put progressColor property in this bust it just showing from beginning to end im trying to achieve this semicircle with final color in gradient.

```
    <h3>Circliful</h3>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div id="semi-circle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">< 
/script>
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.circliful.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() { // 6,32 5,38 2,34
        $("#semi-circle").circliful({
            animation: 1,
            animationStep: 5,
            foregroundBorderWidth: 15,
            backgroundBorderWidth: 15,
            percent: 95,
            textSize: 28,
            textStyle: 'font-size: 12px;',
            textColor: '#666',
            halfCircle: 1,
            progressColor: {40: '#1dc080', 60: '#00b6c4', 60: '#00b6c4'}
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link:

https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful/issues/149

Possible reasons:

- plugin is not updated
- gradient is not implemented

The api doc say, that `progressColor` only change color of foreground circle as percents change, so there is no gradient applied.